# how to enable/disable button in eclipse plugin project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to enable/disable toolbar button and menu button on project start.

Here is toolbar code and image[image]

```
 <toolbar
           id="SoCEnterprise.toolbar">
        <command
              commandId="SoCEnterprise.IPXact.handler"
              helpContextId="Generate Help"
              icon="icons/generate16.png"
              id="Generator"
              label="Generate XML (IP-XACT)"
              style="pulldown"
              tooltip="IP-XACT">
        </command>
     </toolbar>
```

and also i need to enable/disable popupmenu button from menu bar. here is code

```
<menu
           label="Generate">
        <command
              commandId="SoCEnterprise.AllOutputs.handler"
              label="All Outputs"
              style="push"
              tooltip="generate all outputs">
        </command>
        <command
              commandId="SoCEnterprise.ipxact2.hanlder"
              label="IPXACT"
              style="push"
              tooltip="ipxact">
        </command>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The enabled state of the handler for the command determines if the menu / toolbar item is enable. So you do this in the `org.eclipse.ui.handlers` extension point where you define the handler.

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
 <handler commandId="commandId"
      class="package.Handler">
   <enabledWhen>

      ... you enabled when expression

  </enabledWhen>
 </handler>
</extension>
```

Comment: how can i access values from program inside <enableWhen> tag?

Comment: i am trying this code <handler
            class="com.agnisys.socmenus.IPXactHandler"
            commandId="SoCEnterprise.ipxact.handler">
         <enabledWhen>
            <equals
                  value="com.agnisys.license.GENERATE">
            </equals>
         </enabledWhen>
      </handler>   where com.agnisys.license.GENERATE is a static variable in license class. i need to enable/disable that button when GENERATE variable returns true/false

Comment: You can use a 'property tester', see the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point